# Redux Form - I get an error when rendering the below custom component? Do not know why?

Tags: react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

I am trying to render the following custom field component using redux-form, i am also passing custom props to the field component, however it keeps giving me an error as below:

> invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {renderValidation}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>       in InputField (created by ConnectedField)
>       in ConnectedField (created by Connect(ConnectedField))
>       in Connect(ConnectedField) (created by Field)
>       in Field (created by LoginForm)
>       in div (created by LoginForm)
>       in form (created by LoginForm)
>       in LoginForm (created by Form(LoginForm))
>       in Form(LoginForm) (created by Connect(Form(LoginForm)))
>       in Connect(Form(LoginForm)) (created by ReduxForm)
>       in ReduxForm (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in section (created by Login)
>       in Login (created by Connect(Login))
>       in Connect(Login) (created by Route)
>       in Route
>       in div
>       in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
>       in ConnectedRouter
>       in Provider
>       at invariant (invariant.js:42)
>       at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:6748)
>       at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7659)
>       at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7756)
>       at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7747)
>       at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7881)
>       at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7850)
>       at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8225)
>       at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
>       at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
>
> VM250629:20 The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in InputField (created by ConnectedField)
>       in ConnectedField (created by Connect(ConnectedField))
>       in Connect(ConnectedField) (created by Field)
>       in Field (created by LoginForm)
>       in div (created by LoginForm)
>       in form (created by LoginForm)
>       in LoginForm (created by Form(LoginForm))
>       in Form(LoginForm) (created by Connect(Form(LoginForm)))
>       in Connect(Form(LoginForm)) (created by ReduxForm)
>       in ReduxForm (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in div (created by Login)
>       in section (created by Login)
>       in Login (created by Connect(Login))
>       in Connect(Login) (created by Route)
>       in Route
>       in div
>       in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
>       in ConnectedRouter
>       in Provider
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class InputField extends Component {
    render() {
        const { input, label, id, minlength, maxlength, required, meta: { touched, error } } = this.props;

        console.log('InputField - render', input, label, id, minlength, maxlength, required, touched, error);

        let renderValidation = function() {
            if (touched && !error) {
                return <i className="fa fa-check tm-form-valid"></i>;
            } else if (touched && error) {
                return <i className="fa fa-exclamation-triangle tm-form-invalid tooltip tooltip-effect tooltip-item"><span className="tooltip-content clearfix"><span className="tooltip-text">{error}</span></span></i>;
            }
        }

        return (
            <span className="input input--isao">
                <input {...input}
                    className="input__field input__field--isao"
                    spellCheck="false"
                    label={label}
                    id={id}
                    minLength={minlength}
                    maxLength={maxlength}
                    required={required} />
            </span>,

            <label className="input__label input__label--isao"
                htmlFor={id}
                data-content={label}>
                <span className="input__label-content input__label-content--isao">
                    {label}
                </span>
            </label>,

            {renderValidation}
        );
    }
}

InputField.propTypes = {
    input: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    minlength: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    maxlength: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    required: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    meta: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    touched: PropTypes.bool,
    error: PropTypes.string
};

export default InputField;
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the elements you render inside a single element, like a `<div> <span ...> <label ...>  {renderValidation}  </div>` ?

Comment: Thanks @Dario. This worked for me. I was under the impression that as long as you separate each element by a comma it would render. When i wrapped it into a <div></div> voila, magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class InputField extends Component {
    render() {
        const { input, label, id, minlength, maxlength, required, meta: { touched, error } } = this.props;

        console.log('InputField - render', input, label, id, minlength, maxlength, required, touched, error);

        let renderValidation = function() {
            if (touched && !error) {
                return <i className="fa fa-check tm-form-valid"></i>;
            } else if (touched && error) {
                return <i className="fa fa-exclamation-triangle tm-form-invalid tooltip tooltip-effect tooltip-item"><span className="tooltip-content clearfix"><span className="tooltip-text">{error}</span></span></i>;
            }
        }

        return (<div className="wrapper">
            <span className="input input--isao">
                <input {...input}
                    className="input__field input__field--isao"
                    spellCheck="false"
                    label={label}
                    id={id}
                    minLength={minlength}
                    maxLength={maxlength}
                    required={required} />
            </span>,

            <label className="input__label input__label--isao"
                htmlFor={id}
                data-content={label}>
                <span className="input__label-content input__label-content--isao">
                    {label}
                </span>
            </label>,

            {renderValidation}
        </div>);
    }
}

InputField.propTypes = {
    input: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    minlength: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    maxlength: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    required: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    meta: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    touched: PropTypes.bool,
    error: PropTypes.string
};

export default InputField;
```

As mentioned above, `render()` can return only one element.

Answer (score 0):

The `render()` method have to return a single HTML node. 
As Dario said in his comment, if you wrap it all in a `<div>`, it will work.

Comment: Thanks @VictorBaron.